# How to generate a conditional random variable in R?

Tags: r, distributions, random-variable, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose there is a sample $X\sim N(0,1)$

```
x<-rnorm(100).
```

If I want to generate a conditional random variable
 $Y|X\sim U(0,1)$, how can I get this conditional sample in R?

---

Actually, I want to run a simulation for the Skorohod representation of quantile regression.
$$Y=X^\prime\beta(U),\quad U|X\sim U(0,1)$$
So that the $\tau$th quantile linear regression coefficient is $\beta(\tau)$.
I think the comment and answer below is correct.

The simulation I did is as following:

Let $U\sim U(0,1)$, $X\sim |N(0,1)|$, $\beta(u)=0.5(1+u)$.

Generate $y=x\beta(u)$.

So that if we do a quantile regression between $y$ and $x$, then the $\tau$th quantile linear regression coefficient is just $\beta(\tau)$. Note that 0.5497972643 is very close to 0.55

```
library("quantreg")
n=10000
u=runif(n)
b=0.5*(1+u)
x=abs(rnorm(n))
y=x*b
fit=rq(y~x,tau=0.1)
> fit
Call:
rq(formula = y ~ x, tau = 0.1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)             x 
-0.0002284288  0.5497972643 
> 1.1*0.5
[1] 0.55
```

Thanks for all the comments and answers!

Comment: You need to know how it is conditioned, i.e. pdf of $y|x$.

Comment: Can you clarify the notation $Y\mid X  \sim U(0,1)$ - did you really intend $Y$ and $X$ to be independent (As interpreted in the answer)? It might help to explain how the need to generate this sample arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $Y|X \sim U(0,1)$, then regardless of the value of $X$, $Y|X$ is always $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. In other words, the conditional distribution does not depend on $X$ (Compare this with a situation in which $Y|X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,X)$, where now we have to know the value of $X$ to ascertain the distribution of $Y$).

Thus, assuming there are no typos in your question, the following code will do:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- runif(100)
```